How can we check the format of the date coming in Payload using Dataweave
We have a requirement where the source is a file and it has a date field that can contain different date format. For example MM/dd/yyyy or MM/dd/yy or MM-dd-yyyy or MM-dd-yy. This date field we want to finally convert into MM-dd-yyyy
How can we check the date format from source and accordingly transform it into required format? or is there a way where we can transform any date format into desired format?
Input:
[
    {
        "date": "01-03-2023"
    },
    {
        "date": "01-03-23"
    },
    {
        "date": "01/03/2023"
    },
    {
        "date": "01/03/23"
    }
]

Expected Output: format "MM-dd-yyyy"
[
    {
        "date": "01-03-2023"
    },
    {
        "date": "01-03-2023"
    },
    {
        "date": "01-03-2023"
    },
    {
        "date": "01-03-2023"
    }
]

Thank you in advance

"01/0/23" this is not a valid date. What rules are you using to convert it to "01-03-2023"? What is the output format? dd-MM-yyyy?

corrected the input date and updated the expected output format

You can use the try()/orElseTry()/orElse() functions to try different date patterns to convert the inputs. If no pattern matches then I returned null to signal the error (in the last orElse(). You can add additional input patterns by adding orElseTry() calls. One benefit of this solution is that avoids using string manipulation for handling dates, which is an anti-pattern.
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::Runtime
fun attemptDateParsing(d:String)=
    (try(() -> d as Date {format: "MM-dd-yyyy"} as String { format: "MM-dd-yyyy" })  
    orElseTry (() -> d as Date {format: "MM-dd-yy"} as String { format: "MM-dd-yyyy" }) 
    orElseTry (() -> d as Date {format: "MM/dd/yyyy"} as String { format: "MM-dd-yyyy" }) 
    orElseTry (() -> d as Date {format: "MM/dd/yy"} as String { format: "MM-dd-yyyy" }) 
    orElse (() -> null))
---
payload map { date: attemptDateParsing($.date)}

Output:
[
  {
    "date": "01-03-2023"
  },
  {
    "date": "01-03-2023"
  },
  {
    "date": "01-03-2023"
  },
  {
    "date": "01-03-2023"
  }
]


Yeah that's true. I thought it converted so it worked like yy but seems like it isn't. I will delete it to avoid confusion

If you use: default, it works like try/catch.
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun convertToDateFormat(dateStr:String, inputDateFormatList:Array, outputDateFormat:String):Object =
inputDateFormatList reduce (
    (item, acc={found: false, cDate: ""}) -> 
        do {
            var cDate = (dateStr as Date {format: item}) default "INVALID_DATE"
        ---
        (
            if(!(acc.found) and (cDate is Date))
                acc  update {
                        case .found -> true
                        case .cDate -> cDate
                }
            else
                acc
        )
    }
)

So you can:
var dateFormatList = ["MM-dd-yyyy", "MM-dd-yy"]
var outputDateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
---
(convertToDateFormat("01-03-23", dateFormatList, outputDateFormat)).cDate

And the output
{
  "a": "01-03-23"
}

The function convertToDateFormat will "loop" through all possible formats in inputDateFormatList and try to convert to the outputDateFormat.
It is another way to implement it.
